# Get a specific line from a string in ANSI C

Tags: c, string, ansi-c

I need to get a specific line in a char * but im doing something wrong with the arrays... any ideas how can I do it?

The function is something like this:

`char * line get_line(char * code, int num_line);`

where should i put the frees and mallocs?

thanx!

Im sorry... I had to be more explicit, this is how I solved it (is in spanish)

```
char* obtenerLinea(char*cont, int numLinea)
{
    int32_t lineaActual=0,comienzoLinea=0,caracterActual=0;        // línea
    char *cadena;

    while(lineaActual<numLinea)
    {
        comienzoLinea=caracterActual;
        while(contenido[caracterActual]!='\n')
            {caracterActual++;}
        caracterActual++;
        lineaActual++;
    }
    cadena = sub_string(contenido, comienzoLinea, caracterActual-comienzoLinea);

    return cadena;
}
```

Comment: You need to give us more context, and provide a larger code snippet showing the usage.

Comment: Seems you missed an assignment sign?

Comment: you should give some examples that can tell us the detail.

Comment: Maybe you should show us the code you've written that is doing something wrong with the arrays.  You also need to specify the desired usage.  Is the newline required in the output string, for example?  What happens if you request line N and there are only M lines in the string (and N > M)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My short answer is: put the `malloc` inside the function and the `free` outside.

But the way you asked your question, it's almost like saying "I want to throw a tea party...  Where should I put the table and chairs?"

What I mean is your question is open to interpretation:

1. You *don't* want to modify the input string (even though you've said it's allowed by not making it `const`).
2. You *do* want to modify the input string, and want to return a pointer into it.
3. It doesn't matter whether you modify the input string or not - you still want to copy a string out of it.

Well, it turns out that in cases 1 and 3 above, you'll be making a call to either `malloc` or `strdup` inside the function.  If `malloc`, you'll then copy string data into the new memory.  For `strdup` you'd have to modify the input string to null-terminate the line.  In these cases, you'll return a newly allocated pointer, which the caller is responsible for freeing when they are finished with it.  Note there is also the possibility of using `strndup` without modifying the buffer.

In the case of number 2, there will be no calls to `malloc` or `free` because you're just modifying the buffer and returning a pointer to some part of it.

In all cases, I've assumed that you already know where to call `malloc` and `free` for the input buffer itself!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% clear on what you're asking for, is this the kind of functionality you're looking for:

```
char *get_line(char *code,int line) {
    size_t size = strlen(code);

    size_t current_line = 0;
    for(size_t n=0;n<size;n++) {
        if(current_line == line) return code+n;
        if(code[n] == '\n') current_line++;
    }

    return 0;
}


char *data = "line1\nline2\nline3\nline4";

char *line = get_line(data,2);
```

Comment: Something like this is what i need but... why havent you used malloc?

Comment: This comes down to the "not 100% clear" concern.  You have not told us the semantics of your function, so they have been inferred them from the prototype you provided.  Nothing says the line must be null-terminated or copied into a new string.  This answer is simply returning a pointer to the beginning of the requested line, or NULL.